# Unity - PlayerController doesnt detect that player is standing on the ground

Tags: unity-game-engine

When making a player controller for a 3D game in Unity(school project) I wanted to make the player be able to jump. I wanted to make sure that the player could only jump when he was standing on the ground. To check this I made an array of rays to see if they would collide with the ground.

```cs
// IsGrounded returns false. Rays dont detect ground?
// Ray start is not in Colllider of ground
// Checks if the player is standing on the ground or not

bool IsGrounded ()
{
    Ray[] rays = new Ray[4];
    {
        new Ray(transform.position + (transform.forward * 0.2f) + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down);
        new Ray(transform.position + (-transform.forward * 0.2f) + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down);
        new Ray(transform.position + (transform.right * 0.2f) + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down);
        new Ray(transform.position + (-transform.right * 0.2f) + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down);
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < rays.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(rays[i], 0.2f, groundLayerMask))
        {
            
            Debug.Log("true");//doesnt return true while on ground
            return true;
        }
    }
    Debug.Log("false");//returns false while on ground
    return false;
}
```

I've asked a friend of mine who has been coding in unity for quite some time to help me with this. He says that the script is "good" and should(!) work. Of course the code could be faulty (since it doesn't work as intended), and we would like to know if this is the case/if there would be a better way to code this in general.

The plane the player is standing of is part of the layer it can detect(default), my friend changed this to a dedicated layer to see if the "default layer" was the problem. This didnt help.

He wrote some code(that he layer deleted :sadface: )that detected that the all 4 rays where cast.

The start of the rays are above the ground I want to collide it with, he mentioned that there was more than enough clearance to not have this issue. As I moved it 0.1 up from the origin.

In the end the console returns "false" to me indicating that the rays didnt collide with the mesh of the ground, however We(my friend and I) cant think of any reason why.

Comment: Is `groundLayer` set up correctly - is the ground on that layer? Next, debug the ray using the hit properties: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html e.g. what is the `collider.name`? Code looks OK, you shouldn't need 4 rays, just one - `-transform.up`.

Comment: @Absinthe As far as I know, the `groundLayer` was set up correct. I set the ground to layer `ground` and enable it in the  LayerMask. When implementing the RaycastHit, it did not return anything, meaning it didn't collide(?)

Comment: Try visualising the ray with this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html. Don't forget to enable gizmos in the editor: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html

Comment: @Absinthe When I visualize rays I can see that the lines start above the ground and then intersects it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you don't use **sphereCast** or **boxCast** to solve this problem. Anyway, the code below is a simpler example that you don't need to define the array and long and complicated calculations. Just put the following code as the only required line of the method and set the following variables correctly:

```cs
return Physics.SphereCast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, yOffset,0f), radius, Vector3.down, out groundInfo, yOffset + .1f, groundLayer.value);
```

It is important to define a separate layer for the ground and also check the dimensions of the character carefully. Also, the `groundInfo` variable provides other useful information such as **normal** and **hitPoint**.

```cs
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
[SerializeField] private float radius = .2f;
[SerializeField] private float yOffset = 1f;
private RaycastHit groundInfo;
```